# Difference in syntax when creating an object

Tags: javascript, object

Is there any difference between:

```
NewObject = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

And

```
NewObject = {foo: 'bar'}
```

For they seem to be working in the same way.

Comment: I'd like to know whether there is a difference in data types, for 'foo' is a string, but foo inside the object seems to be a variable, or is it seen as a string by js even though there are no parentheses

Comment: This is a language feature for javascript [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Comment: I mean quotes not parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference. Using quotes is required if the key name is a reserved word or contains special characters:

```
{ 'foo+2' : 'bar' }
{ 'finally': 'foo' }
```

Otherwise no quotes required.

Comment: I'd like to know whether there is a difference in data types, for 'foo' is a string, but foo inside the object seems to be a variable, or is it seen as a string by js even though there are no parentheses

Comment: No, it is ALWAYS a string. If you want to pass a variable as key name, you have to use the `[]` syntax, for example: `var NewObject = {}; NewObject[foo] = 'bar';` <-- this will use the `foo` variable rather than the `"foo"`-string. The notation `NewObject.foo` is equivalent to `NewObject['foo']`. It's up to you which one you prefer to use.

Comment: object literals can be treated as JSON so, if you plan to use it as JSON, `JSON.stringify`-ing your variable will add quotes automatically (not talking about special characters here), but if you create it manually using unquoted properties it'll result in an *Invalid JSON*. `{name : "foo"} // invalid JSON`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have dynamic variables but you can create dynamic properties. For example:

```
arr['a' + 3] = 4;
console.log(arr.a3); //4
```

The answer is that there is not difference.
In this case the appropriate way to do it is by using double quotes `{"a3": 4}` because that is the syntax for JavaScript object notation.